# Recommended continuous integration tools for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, deploy, git, deployment, aws

For companies deploying Magento 2, what CI (continuous integration) tools do you recommend? We use GitHub and commonly deploy to AWS Beanstalk instances, but some of our clients use Linux VMs on Microsoft Azure.

In the past, we have configured Jenkins on our own servers, but we're considering alternatives, including:

- Deploy HQ
- Beanstalk - Seems like you need DeployBot for GitHub integration.
- Codeship
- Others?

## Requirements

1. Must work with Magento 2. Other frameworks like Drupal 8 are nice to have.
2. Must work with GitHub.
3. Should integrate with servers on AWS (either EC2 or AWS Beanstalk) and Microsoft Azure running Linux.

## Helpful Links

**What is the easiest way to deploy from GitHub to a web server?**

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-easiest-way-to-deploy-from-GitHub-to-a-web-server

**How to deploy your code (compares Beanstalk to DeployHQ)**

http://surprisehighway.com/article/how-to-deploy-your-code

Comment: Although the question asks for opinion based answers it's still a valid question. I would like to ask anyone answering to clearly motivate their choice with concrete arguments

Comment: I agree, it would be nice for Magento to open up their CI process to the community as it would be great to be able to able to create customisations and keep in line with the core.